# Design patterns and language suitability

Tags: design-patterns

I'm just getting into design patterns and what I'm reading is that the pattern is *typically* independent of language.

In programming we have OOP and non-OOP (is there a name for non-OOP?).

I've recently been playing with the [template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) and it seems to almost counter-intuitive for OOP. The fact it's just effectively a bunch of "Go To Methods" (reminding me of Pascal to a degree) seems some how 'against' how OOP wants to behave.

Does this mean that some patterns are better suited to languages (and I appreciate that having some thing not perfectly suited doesn't mean it's not suitable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template pattern is actually a very good example of OOP when done properly because you can refer to a group of related objects by their abstract type, and operate on them in a similar fashion because they each implement the same "contract" of methods.  That pattern is said to define algorithm/program structure, but in most basic cases, it's really just [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming).

You could argue that some patterns are better suited to other languages, but you can pretty much use any pattern in any language.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think about it in regards to polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Patterns are independent of languages, but are often specific for a language family. There are patterns common to OO languages, some are common to functional languages, etc.

Let's take a visitor pattern as an example: it is popular in a subset of OO languages which don't support multiple dispatch (C++, Java, C# - short of `dynamic`s). However, it is completely needless in languages where multiple dispatch is a language feature (Common Lisp, Clojure).

With regard to OOP vs non-OOP, there are multiple non-OOP paradigms: functional languages, procedural languages, etc. Many are really multiparadigm-languages, e.g. C++ - it provides features of OO, procedural and functional languages. On the other hand, many people don't consider it a real OO language, as types are not first-class objects in C++, and they are likely right.